# Why can't I pass the this pointer explicitly to a member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, this

The c++ standard (ISO c++11) mentions in **Section 9.3.1** that

> A non-static member function may be called for an object of its class
>   type, or for an object of a class derived (Clause 10) from its class
>   type, using the class member access syntax (5.2.5, 13.3.1.1).

An attempt to compile this code with g++ (version 4.8.2)

```
 class foo{
    public:
         void bar(){
            cout<<"hey there"<<endl;
         }
};
int main(){
    foo obj;
    foo::bar(&obj);
}
```

gives a compile time error because it couldn't match the function's signature. I guess that is expected given what the standard states about calling member functions. 
Since the method will eventually take a form similar to **bar(foo*)** during some stage of compilation, why does the standard asks for member access syntax to call the member function?

Comment: obj.bar();     // this is what the standard is saying

Comment: Basically, C++ takes it upon itself to pass the `this` pointer and doesn't allow you to do it lest you get it wrong.  With an appropriate function (`void foo::bar(foo &t);`), you could write `obj.bar(obj)`, but that is about as silly as it looks.

Comment: The "class member access syntax" of section 5.2.5 is referring to `E1.E2` and `E1->E2` syntax, where E1 is the object and E2 is the member name. To call `bar()`.  You have to use `obj.bar()`.  The `this` parameter is implemented by the compiler using a hidden parameter or CPU register, it is not a public parameter of the declared signature for `bar()`, that is why you cannot pass the object pointer manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets add a *static* member to the class as:

```
 class foo{
    public:
         void bar()     { cout<<"hey there"<<endl; }
         static void bar(foo*) { cout<<"STATIC MEMBER"<<endl; }
};
```

Now if you write this:

```
 foo::bar(&obj); //static or non-static?
```

Which function should be called? In such situation, how would you call *both* of them? What would be the syntax? If you allow one function to have this syntax, you've to abandon it (i.e syntax) for other function. The Standard decided to have *foo::bar(&obj)* syntax for `static` member function, while abandoning it for *non-static* member function.

---

Anyway, if you want to pass `&obj` as argument to the non-static member function, then you can use type-erasure facilitated by `std::function` as:

```
 void (foo::*pbar)() = &foo::bar; //non-static member function   #1

 std::function<void(foo*)> bar(pbar); 

 bar(&obj); //same as obj.bar();
```

Likewise, you could call static member function as:

```
 void (*pbar)(foo*) = &foo::bar; //static member function            #2

 std::function<void(foo*)> bar(pbar); 

 bar(&obj); //same as foo::bar(&obj);
```

Note that at lines `#1` and `#2`, the types of the object `pbar` makes the compiler to choose the correct member function — in the first case, it takes the pointer to the *non-static* member-function while in the latter case, it takes the pointer to the *static* member function.

Hope that helps.